# В каких задачах используется явный или неявный курсоры?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

В каких задачах вообще нужно использовать курсоры: явный или неявный?

В книге Oracle PL/SQL Для профессионалов в 15-й главе подчеркнул такую мысль:

> явные курсоры для однотипных повторяющихся запросов

Что для неявных? И что понимается под однотипными запросами?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вопрос.  Фраза _явные курсоры для однотипных запросов повторяющихся_ - из-за возможных орфографических ошибок, не имеет смысла.  В указанной главе наверняка есть пример того, что имелось ввиду. Привидите его в вопросе.  Также, уточните основной вопрос, он или очень общий, или непонятен. Пока на него возможен только один ответ - во всех задачах, где присутствует SQL запрос.

Comment: Ну, если наример select внутри хранимой процедуры, а из нее хочется ряды вернуть

Comment: "И ответ будет таким: всегда инкапсулируйте однострочные
запросы, скрывая их за интерфейсом функции (желательно пакетной) и возвращая
данные через RETURN".

Comment: К чему относится последняя цитата? Она никак не обьясняет происхождение вышей мысли: _явные курсоры для однотипных запросов повторяющихся_.

Comment: Признаю, моё представление о прочитанном надуманное. Скажите пожалуйста, что мне прочитать что бы ответить на вопрос ?

Comment: Надо не только читать, надо закреплять прочитаное на работающих примерах. Процесс итеративный - прочёл-попробовал, остались неясности, опять прочёл-попробовал. Я накидаю в ответ вам пару примеров. Постараюсь охватить то, что по моему мнению, у вас вызвало неполное понимание.

Comment: Вот перевёл один [вопрос по выбору курсоров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1174960/217579), вам, думаю, тоже будет полезен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полная цитата упомянутая ТС в вопросе и [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1166368/%d0%92-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b/1166731#comment2024843_1166368):

> Поэтому вместо формулировки «явный или неявный?» лучше спросить:
> «инкапсулированный или открытый?» И ответ будет таким: всегда
> инкапсулируйте однострочные запросы, скрывая их за интерфейсом функции
> (желательно пакетной) и возвращая данные через RETURN.

Осмелюсь сокращёно перефразировать: меньше надо уделять внимания выбору между явным и неявным курсором, лучше позаботится о включении повторяюшихся запросов в пакетные функции, скрыв их тем самым от пользователя.

Практические примеры для закрепления материала изложенного в книге:

> Фейерштейн С., Прибыл Б. "Oracle PL/SQL. Для профессионалов" 6-е изд. — СПб.: Питер, 2015.
> Глава 15, подглава "Выбор между явным и неявным курсорами"

Эти примеры помогут понять работу с 2-мя типами курсоров: явными и неявными, в случае явных курсоров со строгой и слабой типизацией результирующего сета данных.

Тестовые данные и спецификация пакета:

```
create table params as 
    select 'key'||level key, 'value'||level value , 'memo about this param' memo
    from dual connect by level<=3;
/
create or replace package democursor as
    type paramtype is record (key varchar2 (8), value varchar2 (16));
    type weakcurtype is ref cursor;
    type strongcurtype is ref cursor return paramtype;
    type paramstype is table of paramtype;
    
    function getParam (key varchar2) return paramtype;  
    procedure openParams (cur out strongcurtype);  
    function getParams (likevalue varchar2) return paramstype;  
end;
/
create or replace package body democursor as
    function getParam (key varchar2) return paramtype is
        param paramtype;
    begin 
        select key, value into param
        from params
        where key = getParam.key;
        return param;
    exception when no_data_found then null;     
    end getParam;
    procedure openParams (cur out strongcurtype) is  
    begin
        open cur for 
            select key, value 
            from params order by key;
    end openParams;
    function getParams (likevalue varchar2) return paramstype is
        cur weakcurtype;
        params paramstype; 
    begin
        open cur for select key, value from params 
        where value like likevalue||'%' order by key;
        fetch cur bulk collect into params;
        close cur; 
        return params;
    end;
end;
/
```

Пример различных случаев использования курсоров и функций с ними из пакета:

```
var rc refcursor;  
declare 
    param1 democursor.paramtype;
    param2 democursor.paramtype;
    params democursor.paramstype;

    function getParam (nth int) return democursor.paramtype is
        cur democursor.strongcurtype;   
        ret democursor.paramtype; 
    begin 
        democursor.openParams (cur);
        <<fechnth>> loop 
            fetch cur into ret; 
            exit fechnth when cur%rowcount = nth or cur%notfound;  
        end loop; 
        return ret;
    end; 
begin 
    param1 := democursor.getParam (key=>'key1');
    param2 := getParam (nth=>2); 
    params := democursor.getParams (likevalue=>'val');
    
    open :rc for 
        select 'got first param' what, param1.key||'='||param1.value param from dual union all
        select 'got nth=2 param' what, param2.key||'='||param2.value param from dual union all
        select 'got val% params' what, params.key||'='||params.value from table (params) params;
end;
/
```

Результат работы:

```
WHAT            PARAM                                                            
--------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
got first param key1=value1                                                      
got nth=2 param key2=value2                                                      
got val% params key1=value1                                                      
got val% params key2=value2                                                      
got val% params key3=value3
```

---

Воспроизводимые примеры выше поместил на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c75efb6dfc83e27c5e0e6120312df1df) для изменения с целью, попробовать и лучше понять отделные моменты работы с курсорами.