# Как выбрать между конвейерной табличной функцией, представлением и курсором?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Вот что, по-моему мнению, уже удалось понять.

Явный курсор используется, потому что запрос в нём можно использовать повторно.
Если используется неявный курсор:

```
for cs in (select ... from tab ... where ...) loop`
```

то запрос будет выполняться каждый раз при использовании курсора. Поэтому, для большей эффективности и используется явный курсор.

Для систематизации кода можно использовать конвейерную табличную функцию (*pipelined table function*) или представление для создания курсора. Хотелось бы знать, зачем использовать одно решение поверх другого.

Вот *за* и *против*, что знаю об этих решениях:

- *ни за, ни против*
  Можно извлечь часть представления или табличной функции с помощью запроса.
- *против*

  Тип записи и тип коллекции, используемые в конвейерной табличной функции, должны быть объявлены. Это временные затраты.
- *за*:
  Можно использовать все возможности PL/SQL внутри конвейерной табличной функции, например, циклы.

Все изложенное выше, правильно? Есть ли другие критерии, которые должен учесть?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to choose between “pipelined table function” , view , and explicit cusor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62372477) от участника [Pierre-olivier Ggendraud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8458083/pierre-olivier-gendraud)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62372477

Answer (score 3):

При открытии обоих типов курсоров, явного и неявного, БД выполняет операцию по парсингу и выполнению запроса. При условии, что курсор остается открытым, результаты можно получить из него позже без повторного запуска. Таким образом, оба эти типа одинаково эффективны в этом отношении.

Явный курсор - это курсор, при котором контролируется его полный жизненный цикл: открытие, выборка и закрытие. С неявным курсором, PL/SQL движок выполнит всё это неявно. Используется явный курсор, когда нужен полный контроль над процессом выборки. Основной сценарий использования для него - [массовая выборка с лимитом](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall.).

Явный курсор также может быть полезен, если надо использовать один и тот же запрос во многих местах кода. Объявите его на уровне пакета, и тогда можно ссылаться на него где угодно:

```
create or replace package pkg as 
    cursor common_cursor is 
    select 1 id, 'common_parameter' par from dual;  
end;
```

Это дает возможность единожды определить общий запрос, что делает код более гибким. Но проблема в том, что все операции открытия, выборки и закрытия повторяются везде там, где он используется. В большинстве случаев, это приводит к большему количеству кода с минимальной пользой.

Теперь о представлении. Вместо того, чтобы объявлять общий курсор, можно поместить его общий запрос в представление:

```
create or replace view common_query as 
    select 1 id, 'common_parameter' par from dual;
```

Затем, можно использовать его в любом другом SQL запросе, как обычную таблицу, например, можно соединить его с другой таблицей (*join*). Этого нельзя сделать с явным курсором. Его нужно предварительно обернуть в конвейерную табличную функцию (*pipelined table function*=PTF):

```
create or replace function pipetf return ... pipelined as
    retvals ...;
begin
    open pkg.common_cursor;
    loop
        fetch pkg.common_cursor
        bulk collect into retvals limit 100;
        exit when retvals.count = 0;
        
        for i in 1 .. retvals.count loop
            pipe row (retvals(i));
        end loop;
    end loop;
    close pkg.common_cursor ;
    return;
end pipetf;
```

Это позволяет использовать курсор внутри другого SQL запроса точно также как и представление:

```
select * from pipetf;
```

Выглядит так, что конвейерная табличная функция намного более сложна в реализации, чем представление. Так зачем утруждаться? Она позволяет делать то, что с представлением это не так просто, например:

- генерировать новые строки или манипулировать результирующим набором данных
- создавать параметризованные запросы

Другими словами, нельзя передать переменную в запрос с представлением:

```
create or replace view common_query (var int) as 
    select c2 from ...
    where  c1 = var
    group  by c2;
```

В то время как, в явном курсоре это возможно:

```
cursor common_cursor (var int) is 
    select c2 from ...
    where c1 = var
    group by c2;
```

Или, возможно использовать это в PTF для создания многоразового, параметризованного запроса:

```
create or replace function pipetf (var int) return ... pipelined as
    retvals ...;
begin
    open pkg.common_cursor ( var );
    loop
        fetch pkg.common_cursor
        bulk collect into retvals limit 100;
        exit when retvals.count = 0;
      
        for i in 1 .. retvals.count loop
            pipe row (retvals(i));
        end loop;
    end loop;
    close pkg.common_cursor ;
    return;
end pipetf;
```

Так что, если есть **необходимость** воспользоваться возможностями PL/SQL для создания новых строк, манипулирования результата запроса, или многократного использования параметризированного запроса, то конвейерная табличная функция *будет* лучшим выбором.

В выпуске 18c были добавлены [полиморфные табличные функции](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/how-to-dynamically-change-the-columns-in-a-sql-query), которые покрывают многие случаи генерации строк/манипуляции результатов. А начиная с 19.6 можно создавать SQL макросы, которые можно использовать для [эмуляции параметризованных представлений](https://blog.sqlora.com/en/parameterized-views-in-oracle-no-problem-with-sql-macros/). Эти новые возможности охватывают большую часть (или все?) случаев использования для конвейерных табличных функций (и даже более того).

Если всё таки нужен только многоразовый запрос без дополнительной обработки, то лучше остановится на представлении.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63490305) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>